# Putting a List of Scriptable Objects inside of another Scriptable Object

Tags: unity, scriptable-object

I'm making a word game in Unity.

I've made two Scriptable Objects.  The first one is for FeemData.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New FeemData", menuName = "Feem Data", order = 51)]

public class FeemData : ScriptableObject
{
[SerializeField]
public string feemName;

[SerializeField]
public string Neem;

[SerializeField]
public Int32 neemNumber;

[SerializeField]
public string coreGrapheme;

[SerializeField]
public string shadowString;

}
```

And the second one is for NeemData

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New NeemData", menuName = "Neem Data", order = 51)]

public class NeemData : ScriptableObject
{
[SerializeField]
public string neemName;

[SerializeField]
public string feemText;

[SerializeField]
public Color feemColor;

}
```

Right now, the NeemData Scriptable Object has a string field called feemText.

In actuality, each Neem can have multiple Feems.  I'd love to turn the feemText into a List of Feems, so that I can drag and drop the relevant Feems into the Neem in the Inspector.

Any suggestions on how to edit the NeemData Scriptable Object to include a List of Scriptable Objects (in this case, the FeemData)?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a public or serialized `List<FeemData>` (or an array `FeemData[]`). Like so:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New NeemData", menuName = "Neem Data", order = 51)]
    
public class NeemData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string neemName;
    
    [SerializeField]
    public string feemText;
    
    [SerializeField]
    public Color feemColor;
    
    //Do this
    [SerializeField]
    public List<FeemData> Feems;
    
}
```

Comment: Amazing Harsh, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!  It worked perfectly.